# How to create an object of a class only once in a Multi Step form PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a class formhandller like this

```
<?php
include "config.php";

class formhandller {

    var $dbinstance;
    var $lastinsertedid;//The id from the basic information tabel 


    function __construct(){
        $this->connectDb();

    }

    function pdoMultiInsert($tableName, $data, $pdoObject){

    //Will contain SQL snippets.
    $rowsSQL = array();

    //Will contain the values that we need to bind.
    $toBind = array();

    //Get a list of column names to use in the SQL statement.
    $columnNames = array_keys($data[0]);

    //Loop through our $data array.
    foreach($data as $arrayIndex => $row){
        $params = array();
        foreach($row as $columnName => $columnValue){
            $param = ":" . $columnName . $arrayIndex;
            $params[] = $param;
            $toBind[$param] = $columnValue; 
        }
        $rowsSQL[] = "(" . implode(", ", $params) . ")";
    }
    //Construct our SQL statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (" . implode(", ", $columnNames) . ") VALUES " . implode(", ", $rowsSQL);

    //Prepare our PDO statement.
    $pdoStatement = $pdoObject->prepare($sql);

    //Bind our values.
    foreach($toBind as $param => $val){
        $pdoStatement->bindValue($param, $val);
    }

    //Execute our statement (i.e. insert the data).
    try {

                return $pdoStatement->execute();

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                var_dump($e->getMessage());
                //show error
                error_log($query." :".$e->getMessage(). "\n", 3, getcwd() . "/var/tmp/sql_error.log");
                exit;
            }

}

    private function connectDb(){

            try {

                //create PDO connection 
                $this->dbinstance = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
                $this->dbinstance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                //show error
                error_log($query." :".$e->getMessage(). "\n", 3, getcwd() . "/var/tmp/sql_error.log");
                exit;
            }

    }

    public function postBasicinformation(){

        //Add the variables coming from the form .

         $stmt = $this->dbinstance->prepare('INSERT INTO basic_information (company,name,designation,email,direct_line,mobile) VALUES (:company, :name,  :designation, :email, :directline, :mobile)');

            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':company' => $_POST['company'],
                ':name' => $_POST['name'],
                ':designation' => $_POST['designation'],
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':directline' => $_POST['directline'],
                ':mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
            ));

        $this->lastinsertedid = $this->dbinstance->lastInsertId('id');

        //echo $this->lastinsertedid;
        //$this->dbinstance=null;
    }

    public function postProjectawards(){
        //An example of adding to our "rows" array on the fly.


                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_POST['nominee_company']);$i++){

                    $rowsToInsert[] = array(
                        'biid' => $this->lastinsertedid,
                        'award_type' => 'pa',
                        'category' => $_POST['nominee_category'][$i],
                        'company' => $_POST['nominee_company'][$i],
                        'name' => $_POST['nominee_name'][$i],
                        'designation' => $_POST['nominee_designation'][$i],
                        'award_title' => $_POST['nominee_title'][$i],
                        'contact' => $_POST['nominee_contact'][$i],
                        'email' => $_POST['nominee_email'][$i],
                        'remark' => $_POST['remarks'][$i]
                    );

                }
            //var_dump($rowsToInsert);
            //Call our custom function.
            $y =$this->pdoMultiInsert('nominee', $rowsToInsert, $this->dbinstance);

            //$this->dbinstance=null;

    }

}
```

Now my redirect page is like this

```
<?php
include "controller/formhandller.php";

$x = new formhandller();

if(isset($_POST['steps'])){
    if($_POST['steps']==1){

        $x->postBasicinformation();
        $url = "nominee.php";
        header('Location: '.$url);
        die();
    }
    if($_POST['steps']==2){

        $x->postProjectawards();
        $url = "nominee2.php";
        header('Location: '.$url);
        die();
    }

}
else {
        header('Location: '.'index.php');
        die();
}
```

When I am saving the first step that is using `postBasicinformation()` this function .

It saves in a table called `basic_information` and gets the id of the inserted row and initialize it to the variable

`$lastinsertedid`

I  want to use this variable in all the next steps to store in other tables.
But right now I am getting `NULL`

any Idea

Thanks.

Comment: If you are getting issues `error_reporting(0);` is not a good idea, its not a great idea anyway unless you are trying to hide the fact that your code is full of errors from your clients

Comment: You have set PDO to Exception Processing. But you do not do the `prepare and execute` in `postBasicinformation()` inside a `try/catch` Likely that that query is failing. **Process errors, dont ignore them**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am updating my code on the basis of your comments thank you , But my main problem is to create the object only once in the hole process , I am new to this it would be really helful if you can comment something about that as well

Comment: Virkam, I only see one instantiation of your `formhandller` class inside what you call your `redirect page` and it is this line `$x = new formhandller();`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes , But in the next step if i do `echo $this->lastinsertedid ` it shows NULL, I think the Class is initialized again and again When my redirect page is loaded

Comment: That is probably due to either the INSERT query failing for some reason, or there is no Auto-Increment column in that table

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tested both insert query is correct and it is echoing the same id also in the first step , But I am going to check it again,  Although I can add a session variable and fix the complete issue but I think thats not the right way to go forward

Comment: Ah I think I spotted something, there is no parameter to the `->lastInsertId()` function call, you have `$this->dbinstance->lastInsertId('id');` so remove the `'id'`

Comment: Also just checking: This other code you speak about, where you want ot use this `lastinsertid`. It is in the `redirect page` and not in a totally different script **Right?**

Comment: @RiggsFolly the code is in the class it self ` postProjectawards()` I am using this function in the redirect page using the same object `$x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting confused about the life cycle of a php script.

Anything you do in `xxx.php` is lost once that script finishes. All objects instantiated during the execution of `xxx.php` with be lost forever once it finishes.

If you want to preserve some information created in `xxx.php` for use in `yyy.php` you have to save it somewhere, either a file or a database or the SESSION or possibly a caching system.

I think this is where you are getting confused. So as you said in a comment if you want to use this lastinsertid in another script the most obvious place to save it between scripts is the `$_SESSION` array

Comment: yeah I think thats the only way I think I can go forward , Also what about SINGLETON ? way its bit paintaking but I think it will work , Probably I will try that on weekend .

Comment: You will get the same problem. Once a script terminates the object is lost. If you have to preserve this information between 2 different scripts a SINGLETON Object will make absolutely ZERO difference